# How to force "Debug Console" in vscode to accept gdb commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to issue some `gdb` commands in vscode's `Debug Console`, but fail

[image]

why and how to fix?

Answer (score 12):

From the Visual Studio Code [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug):

> For the C++ (GDB/LLDB) debugging environment, you can execute GDB,
> LLDB and LLDB-MI commands directly through the debug console with the
> **-exec** command, but be careful, executing commands directly in the debug console is untested and might crash VS Code in some cases.

E.g. for debugging child process after fork:

```
-exec set follow-fork-mode child
```